# Levenshtein distance

Tags: nlp, levenshtein-distance

I would like to know if there is any algorithm that returns the amount of insertions, deletions and substitutions between two words. Most algorithms only return and integer with the distance between the two words but I would like to also have how many of each one are needed. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen an implementation that exposes the individual add, delete, substitute counts.

[This](http://hetland.org/coding/python/levenshtein.py) is a publicly-available python implementation of the levenshtein algorithm. You should be able to hack this into what you're looking for.